# Visual studio doesn't debug on crash

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with 3 projects. 1 class library, 1 ASP.net web project and 1 Console application.

The class library and the console app were added after the asp.net web site.
The Console application is the startup project.

I have now the problem that when the app crash it doesn't show me where it crashed in visual studio. The debugger is attached.

How can I make Visual Studio to show me where the app crashed?

Comment: Why do you have a console application for a ASP.NET project?

Comment: Are you sure that you're in debug mode? make sure you haven't accidentally changed to something else.

Comment: The console app listen on a udp port. I don't think that I can do it with asp.net. The app will be a service on the computer when it works completely.

I'm running in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual studio, if you select Ctrl+Alt+E you should select each exception that appears in the "Exceptions" box, this should get your code to hit the line that is throwing the exception.  If Ctrl+Alt+E doesn't work, just go to Debug->Exceptions in the menu.

And make sure you are running your application in DEBUG mode.  Good Luck!